# Every time redeploying application to get updated file content in Glass Fish server

Tags: java, glassfish

I am Creating a XML file dynamically using struts2 in web-inf directory and calling the XML file in jsp but the problem i am facing is the file is not updating when ever i override  it,i need to redeploy every time.How can i sort out this problem,where should i create dynamic files in Glasssfish server

Comment: Which XML file are you creating dynamically?

Comment: @RobinGreen i am creat XML file to generate a FUSION chart.The XML contain the data.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically created files should not be saved within application directory.

What you are experiencing is correct, if do so, you have to redeploy the application. Save the files outside application directory, in a data directory.

If your application is deployed in a clustered environment, you have to make sure the data directory can be accessed by all the servers in the cluster.

Comment: could  you  please Elaborate this.

Comment: I am assuming that your XML files are expensive to create. If its not, then you shouldn't store these files, create them on the fly. If you still want to store them somewhere, then they should be stored in a directory outside of your application (war file). And access this directory from your application using fully qualified path (e.g /data/xmls). If its a clustered environment, 'data' directory should be a shared directory across all servers. Concept of shared directory differs across different OS. Alternatively, you can store the XMLs in database also.